# C++ regular expressions fails, while online checker works

Tags: c++, regex

I have this code:

```
class Clazz {
private:
  constexpr char _csVersionPattern[] = "^[^\\(\\[\\)\\],]+$";
  //constexpr char _csVersionPattern[] = "(^([\\(\\[])[!-'\\*+\\.-Z\\\\^-z\\|~-]*,[!-'\\*+\\.-Z\\\\^-z\\|~-]*([\\)\\]])$)|(^[^\\(\\[\\)\\],]+$)";
  constexpr char _csIdPattern[] = "^[!-~]+$";
public:
  void func(std::string const& aId, std::string const& aVersion) {
    std::regex idRegex{ _csIdPattern, std::regex::extended };
    std::regex versionRegex{ _csVersionPattern, std::regex::extended };
    auto validId = std::regex_match(aId, idRegex);
    auto validVersion = std::regex_match(aVersion, versionRegex);
    _valid = (validId && validVersion);
  }
};
```

When I call it as `object.func("id", "version");` validId will be true, and validVersion false. If I take the more complex pattern in comment, it also fails. This happens in Visual Studio 2019, and in recent g++ and clang++ too. However, when I try [here](https://www.regextester.com) the same version pattern:
`^[^\(\[\)\],]+$`
it matches the string "version". Also the complex variant works. The patterns compile in std::regex constructor (no exception). What do I do wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/nfonqx) it is on Godbolt. In the original it is C++14, here C++17, both fail.

Comment: I suggest to use Raw string (`R"(..)"`) to avoid the need of escaping.

Comment: When question involves Regular Expression always provide examples: what should be match, what should not be matched, what doesn't work as expected. Use some online compiler to provide live demo, [godbolt is cool for c++](https://godbolt.org/).

Comment: I've added Godbolt run. However, it didn't ate the raw strings, so traditional ones remain.

Comment: You ruined the regex check by having POSIX ERE engine handle the regex parsing. Remove the `std::regex::extended` option, use the default ECMAScript one. That must be `std::regex idRegex{ _csIdPattern };` and `std::regex versionRegex{ _csVersionPattern };`

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought I'm writing POSIX extended. Here are the differences, but it does not fit the screen: https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6c933f4a7d713ef712145c5eb94a1816

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expressions you wrote are ECMAScript compatible, but you selected the `std::regex::extended` flavor, which is [POSIX ERE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04).

In a POSIX ERE pattern, you cannot use regex escape sequences. For example, you cannot put `\]` inside a bracket expression and expect it will match a literal `]`. In fact, it will close the bracket expression prematuarely. The `^[^\(\[\)\],]+$` regex must be written as `^[^][(),]+$` as the `]` that is at the beginning of a bracket expression is treated as a literal `]` char (this is called *smart placement*, `-` must be used at the end of a bracket expression, by the way).

The easiest fix here though is to remove the `std::regex::extended` option and use the default ECMAScript one:

```cpp
std::regex idRegex{ _csIdPattern };
std::regex versionRegex{ _csVersionPattern };
```